# What are the most popular areas to do private pilot flight training in the United States?

Tags: flight-training

Are there any **statistics on the most popular states to do private pilot flight training in the USA** or a similar measure?

I know Florida is very well visited, but I was wondering if there were other states which also have high number of students.

Comment: By statistics do you mean number of student pilots getting enrolled, or percentage of students getting their PPL?

Comment: Enrolled students would be great :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The FAA has a document on their website which breaks knowledge tests down by FSDO rather than state, and it gives a good idea of where the most training is taking place.

It is called: [2013 Airmen Knowledge Tests by Region and FSDO](http://www.faa.gov/data_research/aviation_data_statistics/test_statistics/media/2013/annual/2013_Airmen_Knowledge_Tests_by_Region_and_FSDO.pdf), and lists the following Regions/FSDO's as processing the most knowledge tests (in descending order)<sup>1</sup>:

> **Southern 28,333**
> Orlando 9,996
> South Florida 5,958
> Alabama & NW Florida 4,680
> Atlanta 3,882
> Tampa 2,504
>
> **Western Pacific 18,416**
> Scottsdale 6,053
> Riverside 1,556
> San Diego 1,463
> Sacramento 1,460
> Long Beach 1,327
> Fresno 1,270
> Los Angeles 1,142
> San Jose 1,121
>
> **Southwest 15,943**
> Dallas 2,731
> Fort Worth 2,581
> Houston 2,438
> Oklahoma City 2,347
> San Antonio 2,321
>
> **Eastern 14,552**
> Richmond 1,956
> Greensboro 1,366
> Farmingdale 1,280
> Philadelphia 1,198
> New York City 1,069
> Boston 1,041
>
> **Great Lakes 11,860**
> Fargo 2,120
> Dupage 1,414
> Indianapolis 1,358
> Minneapolis 1,142
> East Michigan 1,111
>
> **Northwest Mountain 9,784**
> Denver 2,205
> Portland 2,131
> Salt Lake City 1,964
> Seattle 1,611
>
> **Central 9,019**
> Nashville 4,293
> Wichita 1,304
>
> **Alaskan 812**

Based on this data, I would say that the areas surrounding the Orlando, Scottsdale, South Florida, Alabama & NW Florida, Nashville, and Atlanta FSDO's are the most popular training areas, with the Southern region being the most popular by far.

---

<sup>1</sup> To improve readability, all FSDO's with less than 1,000 tests have been removed.  See the source data for the complete list.

Comment: Excepting Alaska with only 812 State-wide.

Answer (score 2):

There are two popular areas:  1) Where you live.  Most pilots desiring to fly for fun train near their home and family, and 2) Where the weather is good.  aka somewhere down south, Arizona and Florida are the most popular.  Why?  Fewer no-fly days.  There is a reason that ERAU has branches in Florida and Arizona.

Answer (score 0):

I used to train in the Phoenix area. Very busy. Lots of Chinese, Vietnamese, Dutch, Germans, Englishmen etc. (CAE Oxford, KLM Flight Academy (although I believe they recently ceased their training facility there) and many others. I'm sure this will not satisfy as an answer since these are all CPL training facilities and not PPL. Thought it would be interesting to share though. Cheers.